# Отображение картинок из модели Django

Tags: python, django, изображения, django-model, django-template

Добавил в админке item с названием и картинкой.

Файл `/item/models.py`:

```py
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.IntegerField(max_length=255)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products_images/')
    note = models.TextField(null=True)
```

Шаблон `/item/template/product_list.html`:

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<h1> product list</h1>
{% for product in products %}
<div class="product_card">
    <img src="{{ product.image.url }}" alt="{{ product.name }}">
    <h2>{{ product.name }}</h2>
    <h2>{{ product.price }}</h2>
    <h2>{{ product.note }}</h2>
</div>
{% endfor %}
</html>
```

После того как добавил два товара появилась папка `media/product_images` в корневой папке проекта. В ней как раз два изображения с админки.
Но когда я открываю `product_list.html` - вся информация о товаре отображена кроме картинки. В консоли пишет что не удалось найти.

Comment: скорее всего неправильно подключили media файлы в settings.py и urls.py проекта

Comment: MEDIA_URL = '/media/'  

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/media/')


urls.py : urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Comment: проверь путь изображения

Comment: В каком месте его проверить ?
На сайте в img путь стоит : product_images/imagename.png

Comment: добавь в urls.pt from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ...
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

settings.py проверь 
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

Comment: `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/media/')` ну тут ошибка, надо убрать слэш до и после media

Comment: слэши убрал, результаты пока такие же